JS, Angular. How to export data as a chart in excel?
I'm using Angular 17. I want to export the data into an excel file that contains the data and the chart (based on the data).
I've created the export function with exceljs and file-saver:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import * as ExcelJS from 'exceljs';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  template: `<button (click)="export()">Export</button>`,
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = [
    { Month: 'January', Amount: 521 },
    { Month: 'February', Amount: 625 },
    { Month: 'March', Amount: 12 },
    { Month: 'April', Amount: 42 },
    { Month: 'May', Amount: 534 },
    { Month: 'June', Amount: 708 },
    { Month: 'July', Amount: 13 },
    { Month: 'August', Amount: 345 },
    { Month: 'September', Amount: 645 },
    { Month: 'October', Amount: 879 },
    { Month: 'November', Amount: 325 },
    { Month: 'December', Amount: 630 },
  ];

  export() {
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');

    worksheet.columns = [
      { header: 'Month', key: 'Month', width: 15 },
      { header: 'Amount', key: 'Amount', width: 15 },
    ];

    this.data.forEach((monthData) => {
      worksheet.addRow(monthData);
    });

    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((buffer: any) => {
      const blob = new Blob([buffer], {
        type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
      });
      saveAs(blob, `Export.xlsx`);
    });
  }
}

Output: 
But I don't know how to generate the chart in the excel file.
Desired output: 

ExcelJS does not have chart support, please look for alternative libraries!
Gitub issue 1
Gitub issue 2
Gitub issue 3

Is it possible to achieve this with JS, jQuery, or any workarounds?

@NhutTruong maybe try out officeJS
